# Build a query to return both a user and the user's friends

Tags: sql

I have a friends list table where I keep the friendship relationship between two users and then join their posts etc:

```
(user_a, user_b, relation type)
```

Here is some sample data:

```
u_f_id | user_a | user_b | relation_type 
----------------------------------------
  12   | 20     |  23    |    1           //friend
  13   | 30     |  20    |    2           //family
```

I also have a users table where where I keep the user's name and details.

I'm looking to build a query that returns both a user *and* their friends. For example, I need user 20's friends if it appears in `user_a` or `user_b`.

I tried the following:

```
SELECT CASE
         WHEN user_friends.user_a = 20 THEN user_friends.user_b
         ELSE user_friends.user_a
       END AS friend,
       user_friends.*
FROM   user_friends
WHERE  user_friends.user_a = 20
        OR user_friends.user_b = 20
```

Comment: would you please tell what you tried for this?

Comment: You can use a `LEFT JOIN` or a `UNION`, but without your table structure and a sample query it's impossible to be more specific.

Comment: be more specific. post more details. first suggestion: you already got the 'root user' of a circle of friends, if you identify his friends by id or name of him.

Comment: Surprising how fast this question was downvoted and how many close votes it got (4 / 18 visitors). With just a little re-phrasing, it wouldn't be such a bad question

Answer (score 0):

Here are your users.

```
select 
    case user_a when 20 then user_b else user_a end as user_id
from user_friends
where 20 in (user_a, user_b)
and relation_type=1
union 
select 20
```